# How to initialize and append to array of type datetime?

Tags: python, datetime

The problem is initializing an empty array of type Datetime, appending values of type `datetime` to it in a `for` loop, and then choosing values that fall within a certain range.

I have a script that takes latitude `(chla, 'numpy.ndarray')`, longitude `(chlo, 'numpy.ndarray')`, and Universal Time `(chtime, 'numpy.ndarray')` as input. The timezone offset (`datetime.timedelta`) and Local Time is then calculated.

The eventual output should be locations between the range 08:00 - 16:00 LT.

The value `timezone.utcoffset(dt)+chtime[i]` is the correct type (`datetime.datetime`), but after being appended to the local_time array, it becomes type `list`.

I've tried declaring it as a numpy array, numpy array of `dtype=datetime`, and `local_time = np.datetime64([])`

EDIT: added `local_time = np.array(local_time)` before `indicest = np.where((local_time >= start) & (local_time <=end))`

Error now reads:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.time'
```

```py
import numpy as np
import datetime
import pytz
from timezonefinder import TimezoneFinder

tf = TimezoneFinder()
start = datetime.time(hour=8, minute=0)
end = datetime.time(hour=16, minute=0)  
local_time = []

for i in range(0, np.size(chtime)):

     anotherObj = tf.closest_timezone_at(lng=chlo[i], lat=chla[i], delta_degree=10)  
     timezone = pytz.timezone(anotherObj)
     dt = datetime.datetime.now()        
     local_time.append(timezone.utcoffset(dt)+chtime[i])    

indicest = np.where((local_time >= start) & (local_time <=end))
```

Expected output to be list of indices for locations between 08:00 and 16:00, but got error message below:

```
indicest = np.where((local_time >= start) & (local_time <=end))

'>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'datetime.time'
```

Comment: your local time is a list and the start and end are actually time stamps.

Comment: your `local_time` is a list, do a `np.array(local_time)` to convert list to numpy array and the do np.where

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, albeit not the format that I was aiming for. Rather make local_time a variable and add an if-statement within for-loop:

```
    for i in range(0, np.size(indicesla)): 

        anotherObj = tf.closest_timezone_at(lng=chlo[i], lat=chla[i], delta_degree=10)  
        timezone = pytz.timezone(anotherObj)
        dt = datetime.datetime.now()    
        local_time = chtime[i] + timezone.utcoffset(dt)

        if start <= local_time.time() <= end:
            newchla[n] = chla[i]
            newchlo[n] = chlo[i]
            chtime[n] = local_time
            n = n+1

    return newchla, newchlo
```

It's heavy-handed but it works :/